# Convert Sparklyr data frame into a SparkR data frame

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

My current approach would be save my `sparklyr` data frame as a parquet file in a tmp folder and use SparkR to read it. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Another approach will be to stay with `sparklyr` and normal R only. But that will be a separate discussion

Comment: I am interested in such an adapter, too.

Comment: Is  there a solution to this yet?